# Why does setting the .center of a UIimage in viewDidLoad() have no visible effect?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var whiteboxselector: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var profilebutton: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var friendsbutton: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var smallcircle: UIImageView!

    // These are my outlets

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Label.text = "Loaded"
        print("Loaded")

        // This is the line that runs but doesn't do anything
        whiteboxselector.center = self.friendsbutton.center
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your problematic line in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, as follows:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    whiteBoxSelector.center = self.friendsButton.center
}
```

Here's more detail on [`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews#).

Also, for readability's sake, you'll want to write variables in camelCase.

Comment: scripting or not, swift clearly states using camelcase, see at: https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/ . It clearly states: "Follow case conventions. Names of types and protocols are UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase."

Answer (score 0):

ViewDidLoad() is called when the UIViewController is loaded into memory. Your subviews are in no way gauranteed to be set and added to the view hierarchy at this point.
Two ways: 
a) make it in viewDid/Will Appear (not so good, as called more times, so you should adopt a lazy behaviour)
b) use Adrian Approach, usign viewDidLayoutSubviews, that as another advantage: you could for example adjust alignment based on new orientation...
c) align in Storyboard...